# Do British English-speakers call American Lieutenants 'lef-tenants' or 'loo-tenants'?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

In British English, the military (and police) rank of 'lieutenant' is pronounced 'lef-tenant'. In American English, it is 'loo-tenant' (approximately).

Are these treated as two distinct pronunciations of the same word, or as subtly different words? E.g., if a Brit is addressing a US Army lieutenant, should they say 'lef-tenant' or 'loo-tenant' (and vice versa)?

Comment: Which grade of US Army  lieutenant? Who would be the ranking officer? Ranking officers can call a subordinate what they want. This seems to be a question for a military.SE , which we do not have.

Comment: There is no lieutenant rank in the British police, only variations of it in the [armed forces](https://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/en/articles/art20130702112133708), for example the RAF has Flight Lieutenant. A Briton referring to an American lieutenant would almost certainly use their usual accent, not an American one (as with any other word). When you copy someone's accent, it can be seen as "taking the mickey".